# A C program that ,given a structure definition, generates a function to allocate and initialise this structure

Tags: c, metaprogramming, code-generation

I found this exercise in an old book on C data structures and it gave the following problem prompt:

> 4. Write a program that, given a structure definition, will generate a C function that allocates and initializes the structure (such a function is called a "constructor"). For example, given the input:

> ```
> struct complex
> {
>     double real;
>     double imaginarry;
> }
> ```

> function `create_complex()` will be created having two arguments of type `double`.

I tried thinking of how to create such a program and my only solution is to use a file to get the struct input and create a new text file in which I write the function.

Is there any other way to approach this problem?
I appreciate it.

Comment: for those interested, the book is called "Data structures: an advanced approach using C". You can find them in local libraries as well as online libraries. I found an online version in archive.org : https://archive.org/details/datastructuresad00esak

Comment: My usual thought process for these kinds of questions is: can I make [a filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(software))? In this case the answer is "YES".

Comment: Are you supposed to parse the text to figure out what you're initializing? Or just write a function that allocates this particular structure? Either way, the solution in 99% of cases is just `struct NAMEOFSTRUCT *make_struct() { return calloc(1, sizeof(struct NAMEOFSTRUCT)); }`; `calloc` *already* combines allocation and initialization (to zero) of an arbitrary number of bytes, so all you need to provide is the `sizeof` for the `struct` in question. More than that would require in-depth knowledge of the struct (should pointers in it be allocated too, or left `NULL`?) that text won't provide.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The struct is supposed to be given as input and the created function would be the output of the program.

Comment: @RaedAddala: Okay, so is just parsing out the first line to fill in the blanks in the template of my comment reasonable? Do you need to handle nameless structs that are only `typedef`ed? Is the function assumed to run in code that sees the struct definition? If so, then the template works, if not (it has to return the pointer based solely on a forward declaration), you'd have to manually compute a fixed value to replace `sizeof`, which gets a little ugly.

Comment: @RaedAddala: Ah, the edit explains more. You need to generate a virtual "constructor", and therefore need to know the members of the struct so you know what to receive. It's still basically just a text parsing problem, just an uglier one (depending on how complex the structs you're required to handle are).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think the problem is how to process nested structures definitions and how to keep track of different structures sizes and to allocate them that's if I assume the structures are well defined and does not contain syntax errors or typos.

Comment: since this is an exercise with no 'right' answer (I looked at the book outline to see if it had 'answers to problems' , it does not) make it what you like. Parse a c text file and generate a c text file. Definite a method for defining a struct in code - ie a struct that describes a struct and use that to generate a constructor. Write code that converts a text c struct into that meta struct format. Write you own compiler since you started parsing c text ....

Comment: @RaedAddala: The prompt you gave doesn't say anything about nested structs. Is that actually in scope? Could you have some weird `complex` based coordinate system where you'd have to handle `struct complex_point { struct complex x; struct complex y; }` or `struct complex_point { struct complex x, y; }` (equivalent definitions, but parsed differently)?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I think I can make it way easier if I just read and write in the same code file to avoid implementations of sizeof as the struct is already known. With the structs already defined in the file, I only have to write the created functions with the right number of arguments and the right type  and then initialise each member with the values given in the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to literally take the struct definition as input and output a function definition that (1) creates a struct of that type and (2) has an argument corresponding to each element of the structure, then you're correct: you'll need to read the source code as a text file and parse the definition manually. If going with this approach, I recommend using [lex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)) and [yacc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) to generate the code that generates the code. Parsing code for an LR grammar like C has a lot of pitfalls

But if our goal is instead to create both the structure and function from a single definition, we *can* do that directly from the source code, using [X-Macros](https://digitalmars.com/articles/b51.html). The trick to these is that we define our data structure in terms of function-like macros, e.g. `#define X STRUCT(complex, ARG(double, real), ARG(double, imaginary))` but we don't define what those macros *do* yet. We then include a special header file.

The header defines the macros, *then* includes `X` (that is, it has a literal `X` in the file; it includes, rather than #includes), which is expanded according to the macro definitions. It then redefines the macros to do something different, and includes `X` again, which in turn is expanded according to the *new* macro definitions.  Thus, we only need to specify the definition once (and don't need to worry about information getting out of sync), but we generate all the different pieces of code that depend on it.

The following example shows how it works; we create both the `complex` struct from your question, and also `struct other { int a; double b; }` to show how it works with multiple type definitions.

### struct_defn.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>

// Here, we expand X into a struct definition
#define STRUCT(NAME, ARGS) struct NAME { ARGS };
#define ARG(TYPE, NAME) TYPE NAME;
X
#undef ARG
#undef STRUCT

// Expand X into a function decl
#define STRUCT(NAME, ARGS) struct NAME *make_##NAME(struct NAME *out ARGS)
#define ARG(TYPE, NAME) , TYPE NAME
X
#undef ARG
#undef STRUCT

// Expand X into a function definition
#define STRUCT(NAME, ARGS) {                \
    if (!out) {                             \
        out = malloc(sizeof(struct NAME));  \
        if (!out) return NULL;              \
    }                                       \
    ARGS                                    \
    return out;                             \
}
#define ARG(TYPE, NAME) out->NAME = NAME;
X
#undef ARG
#undef STRUCT

#undef X
```

### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

// We define each of the structures in terms of the X-Macros, then "call" the macro by including the file.

#define X STRUCT(complex,   \
    ARG(double, real)       \
    ARG(double, imaginary))
#include "struct_defn.X"
/* The above will expand to the following (but without the formatting)
 *
 * struct complex {
 *     double real;
 *     double imaginary;
 * };
 * struct complex *make_complex(struct complex *out, double real, double imaginary) {
 *      if (!out) {
 *          out = malloc(sizeof(struct complex));
 *          if (!out) return ((void *) 0);
 *      }
 *      out->real = real;
 *      out->imaginary = imaginary;
 *      return out;
 * }
 * 
 */


#define X STRUCT(other, \
    ARG(int, a)       \
    ARG(double, b))
#include "struct_defn.X"

int main() {
    struct complex foo;
    struct complex *bar = make_complex(NULL, 2.71828, 42.0);
    make_complex(&foo, 3.14159265, 0.5);

    struct other *baz = make_other(NULL, 4, 2);
    printf("foo: %f, %f\nbar: %f, %f\nbaz: %d, %f\n",
        foo.real, foo.imaginary,
        bar->real, bar->imaginary,
        baz->a, baz->b);
}
```

Comment: So if I have to do the same for any given structure in an input then I only have to get the name of the structure and the type and name of its member and write them in an X macro like the code you have written above                                                              ` #define X STRUCT(NamedParsedFromInput, \
    listed of members : ARG(type,member) )
#include "struct_defn.X" `

Comment: @RaedAddala Yes, although to address a possible point of confusion with regard to "Name**Parsed**FromInput", I was suggesting using an X-Macro to define the structure in the first place *instead* of defining a structure the normal way and then running a parser to generate the X-Macro call.

Comment: https://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387 is another good article about them if you want some more examples.